# MEF not disposing loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, loading, mef, .net-assembly, dispose

I'm using MEF to load assemblies from a local directory and it's working fine. Later when i want to replace one of the loaded assemblies i receive an exception saying that the file is already used by another process. Here is my code :

```
        var moduleList = _service.GetModules();
        List<Module> modules = null;
        string modulesDirPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"PortailModules");

        if (!Directory.Exists(modulesDirPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(modulesDirPath);

        using (GenericModuleLoader<IModule> loader = new GenericModuleLoader<IModule>(modulesDirPath))
        {
            modules = new List<Module>(
                      from p in loader.Plugins
                      select new Module
                      {
                          FullPath = p.FullPath,
                          AssemblyName = p.AssemblyName,
                          Version = p.Version
                      });                
        }
```

In my GenericModuleLoader i'm disposing my CompositionContainer.

Replacing the assembly :

```
foreach (var module in moduleList)
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(module.FullPath);
                if (!modules.Any(x => x.AssemblyName == module.AssemblyName))
                {
                    File.Copy(module.FullPath, Path.Combine(modulesDirPath, file.Name), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(CompareVersion(module.Version, modules.First(x => x.Name == module.Name).Version) == 1)
                    {
                        File.Copy(module.FullPath, Path.Combine(modulesDirPath, file.Name), true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

When copyin file i receive th exception.

Any idea ?

Comment: You cannot unload an assembly from an AppDomain

Comment: What @SLaks is saying is that normally you cannot unload an assembly. The one exception to that is you can unload entire AppDomains. However threads are tied to AppDomains, so it is unlikely you could design a program that could cleanly partially unload an assembly whilst running.

Comment: You could set up shadow copying, or load the assemblies from byte arrays.